# In Space Quest 1 VGA (not EGA) can you end the game with the cartridge?

Tags: pc, space-quest-1

In Space Quest 1 VGA (not EGA) can you end the game with the cartridge?

This ending plays out as mine did, see 1:34:

> "Now, if you'd only been smart enough to bring along the data
>   cartridge containing the construction specifications, we'd be able
>   (to) build a new Star Generator, thereby saving Xenon from the horrors
>   of a rapidly cooling planet. Oh, well. You are just a janitor."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've proven that you destroyed the Orat, (by bringing the Orat part back to the room with the floating talking head) you have to put the cartridge into a machine in the next room.  A message plays which gives you the deactivation code for the Star Generator.

After you are done watching the message, you have to **take the cartridge back out of the playback machine.**  This must be done before you enter the skimmer.  It's small, but if you watch carefully when Roger inserts the cartridge in the machine, you'll see where it sticks out of the control panel.  Use the "hand" to take it.

If you remember to pick it up again, you can carry it with you to the end of the game.

Comment: Ahhhhh!!! That's it! I did this in the EGA game years ago. It must be the same thing! I will have to try it!